# Multiple params asp net mvc 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I already have a city parameter which represent a cityname that I'll search on my DB, everything work well when I do mysite/List?city=mycityname, but what I'm trying to do is that I would also like to do a search by firstname combined with the cityname example 
List?city=mycityname&firstName=myfirstname. How can I do this ? Here is my query for city, I also added the firstname parameter but I don't really know how to add it so it'll filter both.

`public string CurrentFirstName { get; set; }`

```
public ViewResult List(string city, string firstName, int page = 1)
    {
        UsersListViewModel model = new UsersListViewModel
        {
            Users = repository.Userss
            .Where(p =>city == null || p.CityName == city )
            .OrderBy(p => p.UsersId)
            .Skip((page - 1) * PageSize)
            .Take(PageSize),
            PagingInfo = new PagingInfo
            {
                CurrentPage = page,
                UsersPerPage = PageSize,
                TotalUsers = repository.Userss.Count()
            },
            CurrentCity = city
            // CurrentFirstName = firstName
        };
        return View(model);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do some conditional query building like,

```
public ViewResult List(string city, string firstName, int page = 1)
{
    var query = repository.Userss.Where(p => city == null || p.CityName == city);
    if (firstName != null)
        query = query.Where(p => firstName == null || p.FirstName == firstName);

    var model = new UsersListViewModel
    {
        Users = query
        .OrderBy(p => p.UsersId)
        .Skip((page - 1) * PageSize)
        .Take(PageSize),
        PagingInfo = new PagingInfo
        {
            CurrentPage = page,
            UsersPerPage = PageSize,
            TotalUsers = repository.Userss.Count()
        },
        CurrentCity = city
        // CurrentFirstName = firstName
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

Note: i think you should also consider the search criteria on `TotalUsers` calculation

hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can write something like this

```
Users = repository.Userss
        .Where(p =>city == null || p.CityName == city )
        .Where(p=> firstName == null || p.FirstName == firstName)
        .OrderBy(p => p.UsersId)
     // rest of your query
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look into the following code:

```
    public ViewResult List(string city, string firstName, int page = 1)
    {
        UsersListViewModel model = new UsersListViewModel
        {
            Users = repository.Userss
            .Where((p =>city == null || p.CityName == city ) && 
             (p =>firstname == null || p.FirstName == firstName))
            .OrderBy(p => p.UsersId)
            .Skip((page - 1) * PageSize)
            .Take(PageSize),
            PagingInfo = new PagingInfo
            {
                CurrentPage = page,
                UsersPerPage = PageSize,
                TotalUsers = repository.Userss.Count()
            },
            CurrentCity = city
            CurrentFirstName = firstName
        };
        return View(model);
    }
```